# Spring Boot Controller return generic types (A or B)

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics, controller

I develop simple todo-list application with spring boot. And I wanna send common response dto from all request. The data filed in ReponseMessage is Generic because it can be various type.

```
public class ResponseMessage<T> {
    private int statusCode = HttpStatus.OK.value();
    private String message = "";
    protected T data;  // this is generic. it can be many response dto.

    public static ResponseMessage<String> ok() {
        return new ResponseMessage<>("");
    }

    public static <T> ResponseMessage<T> ok(T data) {
        return new ResponseMessage<>(data);
    }

    public static ResponseMessage<Object> noContent() {
        return new ResponseMessage<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.value(), HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.getReasonPhrase(), "");
    }

    protected ResponseMessage(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    private ResponseMessage(int statusCode, String message, T data) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.message = message;
        this.data = data;
    }

    protected ResponseMessage() {}

    public int getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Now i need to make a feature that find a recend todo.

If todo exists, send ResponseMessage.

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "message": "",
  "data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "test",
        "status": "TODO"
    }
  ]
}
```

If todo doesn't exist, send ResponseMessage.

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "message": "",
  "data": []
}
```

Now my controller function return like this.

```
public ResponseMessage<?> findRecent(@AuthenticationPrincipal LoginUser user) {
    Optional<TodoResponse> todo = todoService.findRecent(user.getId());
    return todo.isPresent() ? ResponseMessage.ok(todo.get()) : ResponseMessage.noContent();
}
```

I know that the question mark '?' is not good. so what is better way to return A or B in this case? plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `noContent().data` to null, you can safely assign it any type:

```
public static <T> ResponseMessage<T> noContent() {
    return new ResponseMessage<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.value(), HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.getReasonPhrase(), null);
}
```

Also note that calling `Optional.isPresent()` and then `get()` is something of an [antipattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--). In your case, you can simplify it to this:

```
return todoService.findRecent(user.getId())
        .map(ResponseMessage::ok)
        .orElseGet(ResponseMessage::noContent);
```